# Why can't I set headers after redirect?

Tags: node.js, express

This is my callback after a json request in expressjs(node)

```
function question(req, res){
    request(req, res, function(response){
        //redirect to the right url if page doesn't exist.
        var params = app.req.params;
        if(params.questionId && encodeURIComponent(params.slug) !== response.question.slug){
            app.res.redirect(response.question.url);
        }
        //Render question
        app.res.render('master',response);
    });
}
```

Here is the request:

```
function request(req, res, callback){
    app.req = req;
    app.res = res;
    http.get({
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 80,
        path: req.url,
        agent: false  // create a new agent just for this one request
    }, function(response){
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function(json){
            json = JSON.parse(json);
            console.log(json)
            callback(json);
        });
    });
}
```

If I trigger the `res.redirect` I get the error below. My expectation is that I get redirected to the new url and app.res.render should be rendered. This error keeps being triggered for a while regardless of what url I visit.

```
_http_outgoing.js:344

throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/kristoffer/web/zenqa2.1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/kristoffer/web/zenqa2.1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
    at done (/Users/kristoffer/web/zenqa2.1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:957:10)
    at /Users/kristoffer/web/zenqa2.1/node_modules/mustache-express/mustache-express.js:168:5
    at /Users/kristoffer/web/zenqa2.1/node_modules/mustache-express/mustache-express.js:131:10
    at /Users/kristoffer/web/zenqa2.1/node_modules/mustache-express/mustache-express.js:118:11
    at loadAllPartials (/Users/kristoffer/web/zenqa2.1/node_modules/mustache-express/mustache-express.js:79:10)
    at /Users/kristoffer/web/zenqa2.1/node_modules/mustache-express/mustache-express.js:102:10
    at /Users/kristoffer/web/zenqa2.1/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:232:13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single request only one response will be sent AND You have to set your headers before the response is sent. `app.res.redirect` and `app.res.render` are used to deliver the response. So actually you can use only one of them. Use `return` to exit the code or use `else` condition.

```
function question(req, res){
    request(req, res, function(response){
        //redirect to the right url if page doesn't exist.
        var params = app.req.params;
        if(params.questionId && encodeURIComponent(params.slug) !== response.question.slug){
            return app.res.redirect(response.question.url); // return
        }
        // also you can use else condition here
        app.res.render('master',response);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

after redirecting you should prevent any further code execution.

the http header defines cookies etc. etc.
if you want to set them, do it before you actually close the http header.

the body will start after there are two following line breaks detected in the http stream.
after the body started you cannot add any more header information

as soon as you use a redirect it will queue a http redirect header aswell as a meta redirect inside the htmls body.

Comment: @Himmators simply calling `return app.res.redirect(response.question.url);`